# How many methods are there to find the closed form of $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{ n}}, \textrm{ where } n\in N $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals, reduction-formula

**Latest Edit**

Great thanks to @Quanto for his closed form for

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec^{2n+1} x \ dx=
 \frac1{2^{2n}}
 \binom {2n}n \ln(\sqrt2+1) +\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {2n}k \frac{(\sqrt2+1)^{2(n-k)} - (\sqrt2-1)^{2(n-k)}}{2^{2n+1}(n-k)}, $$

by which the closed form for integrals with **odd** powers can be found as

$$\boxed{\quad  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{2 n+1}}\\=
 \frac1{2^{3n-\frac{1}{2} }}
 \binom {2n}n \ln(\sqrt2+1) +\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {2n}k \frac{(\sqrt2+1)^{2(n-k)} - (\sqrt2-1)^{2(n-k)}}{2^{3n+\frac{1}{2} }(n-k)} } $$

---

Inspired by the [post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-int_0-pi-2-frac-2x-cos-x-sin-x-2-dx?ch=17&oid=126069416&share=51fcd2db&srid=CCOmo&target_type=question), I firstly try to generalise it to **even** powers as
$$
I_{n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{2 n}},
$$

where $n\in N.$

For simplicity, we express the denominator as cosine using compound angle formula.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{n} &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{2 n}} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{\left[\sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\right]^{2 n}} \\
& \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{=}  \frac{1}{2^{n}}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{d x}{\cos ^{2 n} x}\\ & \stackrel{Symm}{=} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} x d x 
\end{aligned}
$$

Letting $t= \tan x$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{n} &= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{n-1} d t \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \int_{0}^{1} t^{2 k} d t \\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n-1 \\
\quad  k
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{2 k+1}}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Examples:
$$
I_{2} =\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{3},I_{5}=\frac{83}{315}; I_{10}=\frac{26206}{230945};
$$

---

However, it is harder to find the integral of **odd** powers. $$
J_{n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{2 n+1}}= \frac{1}{2^{n-\frac{1}{2} }} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n+1} x d x 
$$
where $n=0, 1, 2,…$

I had found a reduction formula for it as
$$
\boxed{J_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{2 n-1}{4 n} J_{n}}
$$

via the reduction formula for $$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n+1} x d x=\frac{1}{2 n}\left[2^{n-\frac{1}{2}}+(2 n-1) \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n-1} x d x\right]
$$

---

Examples

$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{0} &=\sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec x d x \\
&=\sqrt{2}\left|\ln \left|\sec x+\tan x\right|\right]_{0} ^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\\
&=\sqrt{2} \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{aligned}
$$

\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
J_{1} &=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \cdot \sqrt{2} \ln (\sqrt{2}+1) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{2} &=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{8}\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)\right] \\
&=\frac{7}{16}+\frac{3}{16 \sqrt{2}} \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Although I can find the integral with odd powers one by one, I still can’t find its closed form.  **Your help will be highly appreciated**.

Comment: It is trivial but maybe useful to instead consider that $2^{n-1/2}J_n=\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\csc^{2n-1}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: $$J_n=2^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\int_{1/2}^1\frac{1}{t^n\sqrt{1-t}}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: If you consider an incomplete beta function a closed form, plug in the bounds, with limits, for $\int \sec^{2n}(x)dx $ in this [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+1%2F2+beta%28sec%5E2%28x%29%2C+n%2C+1%2F2%29+csc%28x%29+sec%5E%28-1+%2B+2+n%29%28x%29+sec%5E2%28x%29%5E%28-n%29+sqrt%28-tan%5E2%28x%29%29)

Comment: In fact, you can also solve the recurrence relation for $J(n)$ using Mathematica's RSolve, which gives a closed form solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the odd case, substitute $\sec x= \cosh t$ to integrate
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec^{2n+1} x \ d x
 =\int_0^{\ln(\sqrt2+1)}\cosh^{2n}t\ dt\\
=& \ \frac1{2^{2n}}\int_0^{\ln(\sqrt2+1)}\bigg[
\binom {2n}n+2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {2n}k \cosh2(n-k)t\bigg]\ dt\\
= &\ \frac1{2^{2n}}
 \binom {2n}n \ln(\sqrt2+1) +\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {2n}k \frac{(\sqrt2+1)^{2(n-k)} - (\sqrt2-1)^{2(n-k)}}{2^{2n+1}(n-k)} \\
\end{align}

Comment: What a wonderful and beautiful substitution!  Thank you very much for such a good lesson.

Comment: @Lai - my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Maple solves your recurrence as:
$$
J_n=
{\frac {\Gamma \left( n+{
\frac{3}{2}} \right)}{4\,\sqrt {\pi}\Gamma \left( n+2 \right) }  \left( \sqrt {\pi}\sum _{k=0}^{n}{{2}^{k+1}
\frac{\Gamma \left( k+1 \right)}  { \Gamma \left( k+{\frac{3}{2}}
 \right)}}
{2}^{-n}+{2}^{1-n}J_1  \right) 
}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your good idea.